# Having trouble finding a textview by the id

Tags: android, textview, layout-inflater

I use a menu inflater and in every row I give the textview and seekbar an id of i(I use a for loop to give them there id).  When I get the id of the seekbar and I want to insert text into the textview.  The problem I am having is how do I set the text in the textview that has the same value as the seekbar.

```
public static void setNewTipAmount(SeekBar barChanged, double amountForTip) {

 int getID = barChanged.getId(); //get seekbar id


    TextView textView = tipPerPerson.findViewById(getID);// get the textview with same id
            textView.setText("Hello");

}
```

}

Here is the code to how I assign the Id's

```
        for (int i = 0; i < InBetweenUIAndBusinessLogic.getGuests(); i++) {
        View v = in.inflate(R.layout.row_per_person, table, false);
        double tipPerIndividual = (Math.round(InBetweenUIAndBusinessLogic
                .getTipPerPerson() * 100.0) / 100.0);
        String tip = Double.toString(tipPerIndividual);
        tipPerPerson = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tipPerPerson);
        tipPerPerson.setId(i);
        tipPerPerson.setText(tip);
        rows.add(tipPerPerson);
        percentageTip = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        percentageTip.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new myListener());
        double guests = InBetweenUIAndBusinessLogic.getGuests();
        percentageTip.setProgress((int) (100 / guests));
        percentageTip.setId(i);
        table.addView(v);
        bars.add(percentageTip);

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code showing how you assign them ids and add them to the layout. You should keep the ids different unless you are sure of the view hierarchy. Can take a look at your view and give you a possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a simple mapping between `TextView` id and `Seekbar` id. This way each id will be different and you can still get the corresponding item id. Here is my solution:

```
mGuestCount = InBetweenUIAndBusinessLogic.getGuests();

for (int i = 0; i < InBetweenUIAndBusinessLogic.getGuests(); i++) {
    View v = in.inflate(R.layout.row_per_person, table, false);
    double tipPerIndividual = (Math.round(InBetweenUIAndBusinessLogic
        .getTipPerPerson() * 100.0) / 100.0);
    String tip = Double.toString(tipPerIndividual);
    tipPerPerson = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tipPerPerson);
    tipPerPerson.setId(i);
    tipPerPerson.setText(tip);
    rows.add(tipPerPerson);
    percentageTip = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    percentageTip.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new myListener());
    double guests = InBetweenUIAndBusinessLogic.getGuests();
    percentageTip.setProgress((int) (100 / guests));
    percentageTip.setId(i + mGuestCount);
    table.addView(v);
    bars.add(percentageTip);
}
```

Now to find the textview:

```
public static void setNewTipAmount(SeekBar barChanged, double amountForTip) {
    int getID = barChanged.getId(); //get seekbar id

    TextView textView = tipPerPerson.findViewById(getID - mGuestCount);// get the textview with corresponding id
    textView.setText("Hello");
}
```